# GIT - Switching between branches without mixing files

Tags: git

I'm new to git so I'm trying to understand how this works.  I currently have master checked out.  I made some changes to master, lets say I added a logo but I haven't pushed the changes yet.

I then switched to another branch. In this branch I assumed that this would be a fresh checkout of master, but I see my development logo file.  Shouldn't this not be here since it's another branch?  Let me know if I've got this concept all wrong.

Comment: Git will keep any changes which doesn't conflict with the new branch you are switching to. If you had a change in some file which would have conflicts with the same file in new branch, git won't even let you switch branch unless you commit or stash the changes

Comment: I'd echo what @VishalKamat said - this allows you to make some changes, realize that those changes should be on a different branch, and then apply them there. Once you stage the changes, then they stay with that branch.

Comment: Have you added the newly created file to the repo and committed the change? Likely, you haven't

Comment: I have not committed them since they are still in development.

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you can give the commands you're using to do things like "switched to another branch", "pushed the changes", etc.  If you're coming from, e.g. SVN, there can be some subtle differences in how these things actually work, and when it's appropriate to perform which operations.

Answer (score 1):

To make sonething part of a branch, you need to commit it to that branch. If you have uncommitted work in your checkout, the changes will be kept when switching the branch (as long as there are no conflicts).

Committing changes to a branch does not mean that they are there forever. You still need to push the changes to make them (in a way) permanent.

So if you want to work in another branch temporarily, you can commit your changes, switch the branch, work there, commit that work, switch back to the old branch, execute "git reset HEAD~" to get you earlier committed work back as uncommitted changes and continue from there.

Comment: the sentence "committing change doesn't make changes permanent" is ambiguous. Committing change _does_ make changes permanent in your _local_ repo. But to _publish_ them one _usually_ should push those changes into an outer repository.

Comment: True. "permanent" is a strechy word. In some way, changes to a file are permanent, when you press save in the editor, in another way, nothing was permanent, after the sun became a red giant. :)  (damn Enter key ...) What I wanted to say with it is that as long as you have your changes only committed locally, you can still take them back easily. Once, you pushed them to the server, you might not be able to do that, since someone else might controll the server, or the company's policy forbids it, or just because someone else alread pulled the changes you want to get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, use `git stash save`/`git pop` to save/restore your working state before/after you switch branches.